# How to use `regex` to trim a parsed String?

Tags: java, regex, string

I could have used `Decimal Format`, but I must use `regex` in this case.
I have the following String myString = "0.44587628865979384"; I need to trim it to three decimal places, so that is looks like 0.445

I tried the following:

```
String myString = "0.44587628865979384";
String newString = myString.replaceFirst("(^0$.)(\\d{3})(\\d+)","$1$2");
// But this does not work. What is the problem in here?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not `(^0$.)`. It's `(\\d*.)`

```
String newString = myString.replaceAll("(\\d*.)(\\d{3})(\\d+)", "$1$2");
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, one suitable pattern could be "^\d\.\d{3}", though you will have to do a match to retrieve it (i.e. you're fetching what you need, not replacing what you don't need as in your example).

... but, why would you use regex for this job?

Regex is used to find common patterns in text and lets you extract/remove/list them. It is not intended to deal with string measurement

What you need is to *slice* the string into a subset of characters using the substring method:

```
myString.substring(5);
```

If the position of the decimal point varies:

```
myString.substring(myString.indexOf(".") + 4);
```

Remember: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Comment: Although I agree that one should think really hard before using regexes, the alternative given here doesn't work very well. It's certainly possible that there a variable number of digits before the decimal point.

Comment: True, but I would still recommend locating the decimal point and deriving the index for substring from that.

Comment: That sounds much better... if you can update your answer with that you'll have my vote :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String newString = myString.replaceAll"(.*\\....).*", "$1");
```

Comment: Thank you for your previous answer. It worked fine: `String newString = myString.replaceAll("(.*\\....).*", "$1");` The new one does not work...